# Использование Fabric.js и Marionette.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, fabricjs, marionette.js, marionette

Подскажите, как использовать Fabric.js в Marionette.js 2.4.7 ?

Выдает ошибку " have error "Cannot create property 'style' on string 'constructor'".

Пробовал передавать this.ui.canva в итоге ошибка "Cannot set property 'userSelect' of undefined"

Вот код ItemView

```
 define([
        'app',
        'marionette',
        'backbone',
        'underscore',
        'pace',
        'text!templates/constructor/index.ejs',
        'fabric'
    ], function (App, Marionette, Backbone, _, pace, constructorTmpl, fabric) {
        'use strict';

        return Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            template: _.template(constructorTmpl),
            ui: {
                canva: '#constructor'
            },
            onRender: function () {
                var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('constructor');
            }
        });
    });
```

Код index.ejs

```
<canvas id="constructor" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так работает

```
 onRender: function () {
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(this.ui.canva[0]);
    }
```